# Batch up requests in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, concurrency

I'm new to Groovy and am a bit lost on how to batch up requests so they can be submitted to a server as a batch, instead of individually, as I currently have:

```
class Handler {
    private String jobId
    // [...]
    void submit() {
        // [...]
        // client is a single instance of Client used by all Handlers
        jobId = client.add(args)
    }
}

class Client {
    //...
    String add(String args) {
        response = postJson(args)
        return parseIdFromJson(response)
    }
}
```

As it is now, something calls `Client.add()`, which POSTs to a REST API and returns a parsed result.

The issue I have is that the `add()` method is called maybe thousands of times in quick succession, and it would be much more efficient to collect all the `args` passed in to `add()`, wait until there's a moment when the `add()` calls stop coming in, and then POST to the REST API a single time for that batch, sending all the args in one go.

Is this possible? Potentially, `add()` can return a fake id immediately, as long as the batching occurs, the submit happens, and Client can later know the lookup between fake id and the ID coming from the REST API (which will return IDs in the order corresponding to the args sent to it).

Comment: Everything is possible, but you have to write it...

Comment: Waiting till calls to add pauses may cause issues if it there is no pause for a considerable amount of time & you have to batch up 1000s of requests, maybe base the batching on time and a configurable limit. Also what happens if you return a fake id to the caller & the REST call fails? guessing you'll have to undo a bunch of stuff you've just marked as done. Maybe look at GPars & multithread things up.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this might be a good case for gpars which is excellent at these kinds of scenarios.

This really is less about groovy and more about asynchronous programming in java and on the jvm in general.

If you want to stick with the java concurrent idioms I threw together a code snippet you could use as a potential starting point. This has not been tested and  edge cases have not been considered. I wrote this up for fun and since this is asynchronous programming and I haven't spent the appropriate time thinking about it, I suspect there are holes in there big enough to drive a tank through.

That being said, here is some code which makes an attempt at batching up the requests:

```
import java.util.concurrent.* 
import java.util.concurrent.locks.* 

// test code 
def client = new Client()

client.start()
def futureResponses = []
1000.times { 
  futureResponses << client.add(it as String)
}
client.stop()

futureResponses.each { futureResponse ->
  // resolve future...will wait if the batch has not completed yet
  def response = futureResponse.get()
  println "received response with index ${response.responseIndex}"
}
// end of test code 

class FutureResponse extends CompletableFuture<String> {
  String args
}

class Client {
  int minMillisLullToSubmitBatch = 100
  int maxBatchSizeBeforeSubmit   = 100
  int millisBetweenChecks        = 10
  long lastAddTime               = Long.MAX_VALUE

  def batch = []
  def lock = new ReentrantLock()
  boolean running = true

  def start() {
    running = true
    Thread.start { 
      while (running) {
        checkForSubmission()
        sleep millisBetweenChecks
      }
    }
  }

  def stop() {
    running = false
    checkForSubmission()
  }

  def withLock(Closure c) {
    try { 
      lock.lock()
      c.call()
    } finally { 
      lock.unlock()
    }    
  }

  FutureResponse add(String args) {
    def future = new FutureResponse(args: args)

    withLock { 
      batch << future
      lastAddTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }

    future
  }

  def checkForSubmission() {
    withLock { 
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastAddTime > minMillisLullToSubmitBatch ||
          batch.size() > maxBatchSizeBeforeSubmit) { 
        submitBatch()
      }
    }
  }

  def submitBatch() {
    // here you would need to put the combined args on a format 
    // suitable for the endpoint you are calling. In this 
    // example we are just creating a list containing the args
    def combinedArgs = batch.collect { it.args }

    // further there needs to be a way to map one specific set of 
    // args in the combined args to a specific response. If the 
    // endpoint responds with the same order as the args we submitted
    // were in, then that can be used otherwise something else like 
    // an id in the response etc would need to be figured out. Here 
    // we just assume responses are returned in the order args were submitted
    List<String> combinedResponses = postJson(combinedArgs)
    combinedResponses.indexed().each { index, response -> 
      // here the FutureResponse gets a value, can be retrieved with 
      // futureResponse.get()
      batch[index].complete(response)
    }

    // clear the batch
    batch = []
  }

  // bogus method to fake post
  def postJson(combinedArgs) {
    println "posting json with batch size: ${combinedArgs.size()}"
    combinedArgs.collect { [responseIndex: it] }
  }
}
```

A few notes:

- something needs to be able to react to the fact that there were no calls to add for a while. This implies a separate monitoring thread and is what the start and stop methods manage.
- if we have an infinite sequence of adds without pauses, you might run out of resources. Therefore the code has a max batch size where it will submit the batch even if there is no lull in the calls to add.
- the code uses a lock to make sure (or try to, as mentioned above, I have not considered all potential issues here) we stay thread safe during batch submissions etc
- assuming the general idea here is sound, you are left with implementing the logic in `submitBatch` where the main problem is dealing with mapping specific args to specific responses
- `CompletableFuture` is a java 8 class. This can be solved using other constructs in earlier releases, but I happened to be on java 8.
- I more or less wrote this without executing or testing, I'm sure there are some mistakes in there.
- as can be seen in the printout below, the "maxBatchSizeBeforeSubmit" setting is more a recommendation that an actual max. Since the monitoring thread sleeps for some time and then wakes up to check how we are doing, the threads calling the add method might have accumulated any number of requests in the batch. All we are guaranteed is that every `millisBetweenChecks` we will wake up and check how we are doing and if the criteria for submitting a batch has been reached, then the batch will be submitted.

If you are unfamiliar with java Futures and locks, I would recommend you read up on them.

If you save the above code in a groovy script `code.groovy` and run it:

```
~> groovy code.groovy
posting json with batch size: 153
posting json with batch size: 234
posting json with batch size: 243
posting json with batch size: 370
received response with index 0
received response with index 1
received response with index 2
...
received response with index 998
received response with index 999

~>
```

it should work and print out the "responses" received from our fake json submissions.

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up going a different way since I didn't realise there was concurrency happening "above" me, but this will surely be useful to understand if I need to do something similar.